# Email to SMS from field a phone number instead of email address

Tags: email, smtp, sms

currently if i want to use an Email to SMS gateway ... when the person recieves the email they see : me@myemailaddress.com (as the from field on their recieved message on their phone). I was wondering is there a way to make my message send out as a phone number so instead of me@myemailaddress.com

send from field: 999 888 7654 ??

Im not sure how to basically use an SMS to email gateway and send my phone number through?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the SMS gateway you are using but I guess most probably don't have a method for doing what you want. Why don't you use a direct SMS sending service instead (for example, voovox). Of course you have to pay for that whereas the email gateway you are using might be free of charge...

Answer (score 0):

I am reading your question as implying you send an email to a gateway, which then sends the message over as an SMS (to a phone?). Why not send an SMS, directly from your phone, to the other phone? Don't use this gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the email client to display your phone number, just put it in the "real name" portion of the From: header.

```
From: Yours Truly +1-123-555-1212 <you@example.net>
```

Many obnoxious clients will put double quotes around the "real name" as if it wasn't really your name, but that is hardly pertinent here.  Some versions of (?) Outlook will also prefer your First Name last, and your Last Name first.

```
From: "Lastname, Firstname +1-123-555-1212" <you@example.net>
```